# Memory and CPU requirements for Samba server on a virtual linux machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, samba

I want to set up a samba server on a VM in a cloud, for up to 50 clients. What size of VM would I need in terms of RAM, CPU and disk space? The OS would either be CentOS or Ubuntu.

This is not a canonical question as in [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

I want to understand, how much resources a Samba server (not *some* application) with 50 clients (not *some* users) needs.

The question arises, because I can configure a VM with 2GB of RAM or 128GB of RAM.

Comment: Please read the linked question & answer. The point isn't that it answers your question - the point is that we don't answer capacity planning questions for a multitude of reason.